# Sequelize - bulkInsert excluding any entry's that already exist

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am wondering if there is a way to bulkInsert data to add to a database through seeders, but for it to exclude any entry's that already exist.

for example:
**If the database has User with name John and I run a seeder to add users to the database and in the seeders is a entry containing the name John It will skip this entry as it already exists**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [public static async bulkCreate(records: Array, options: object): Promise<Array>](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate) method with `options.ignoreDuplicates` .

> Ignore duplicate values for primary keys? (not supported by MSSQL or Postgres < 9.5)

It's important to add a `unique` constraint to the `name` field.

Here is an example using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"` and `postgres:9.6`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {}
User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await User.create({ name: 'John' });
    // insert multiple instances in bulk
    await User.bulkCreate([{ name: 'teresa teng' }, { name: 'slideshowp2' }, { name: 'John' }], {
      fields: ['name'],
      ignoreDuplicates: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

We seed a user(`John`) firstly, then insert multiple users in bulk. There is a duplicated user(`John`) in the array. The key SQL statement is: `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, that means if the unique `name` conflict, the insert operation will do nothing.

Execution result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "User" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "User" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "User" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'User' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "User" ("id","name") VALUES (DEFAULT,'teresa teng'),(DEFAULT,'slideshowp2'),(DEFAULT,'John') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING *;
```

After executing, check the database:

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "User";
 id |    name     
----+-------------
  2 | teresa teng
  3 | slideshowp2
  1 | John
(3 rows)
```

Comment: what if the name John exist, then we update the data related to John?